# How to change background image for navigation item(button)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationitem

I want to set background image for every navigation item(button) (universal).

How should these images look?

Are there fixed dimensions or it is possible to create repeating background image?

How to programmatically change then this background image?

Thank's for help

UPDATE:

I found this code for changing background of this button but it's no working.

```
UIImage *barButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_background.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And I don't know which dimensions should be.

P.S. I want to change background of button just like you can change background color (self.navigation.controller.nvigationBar.tintColor..)

Answer (score 2):

The code below might solve your problem

```
UIButton *backBtn     = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_background.png"]  ;  
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);  
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Comment: It works. Can you tell me please which dimensions of this background image should be because somewhere there's "Short title" and somewhere is "Very long titleeeee"? And tell me pls is this code for repeat background or fixed because if is fixed it's not universal. tnx

Comment: sry but it doesn't work because I must set action, everything I need is to set background image for left navigation bar item.

Answer (score 0):

u need to create Custom Back Button i m afraid

check this code out

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                      target:nil 
                                      action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Let me know if it worked

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

what about categories? 
For example, you can do so:

```
@interface UIBarButtonItem(JFAdditions)

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage*)img;//add target and action if need

@end

 @implementation UIBarButtonItem(JFAdditions)

 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage*)img
 {
        UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //add background image and text on button, target and action if need, also
    self = [self initWithCustomView:btn];

    return self;
}
```